# NSUserDefaults или как сохранить Картинку

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

Ввел параметр перед классом:

`let defaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()`,
после него есть кнопка которая делает сравнение,а в ней картинка + анимация и ввод текста:

```
if TextField1.text == navigationItem.title {
    self.StarTextField.hidden = false
    UIView.animateWithDuration(4.0, animations: {
    self.StarTextField.frame = CGRect(x: 142, y: -800, width: 316, height: 158)}
    defaults.setObject(StarTextField, forKey: "StarTextFieldData")
    return stopFlashingbutton(stopListening())
} else {
    print("inCorrect TextField")
}
```

вроде как должна сохранить картинку в память. Дальше ViewDidLoad() пишу :

```
defaults.objectForKey("StarTextFieldData")
```

Запуск, краш ... что делать ?)

Ps это Спарка CollectionViewController вместе с ViewController (кнопка находится в VC).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSUserDefaults` не может по дефолту хранить картинки. Поддерживаются только такие типы: float, double, int, Boolean, NSURL, NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, NSDictionary. Я бы сохранял картинку в файл, но можно также перевести её в `NSData` и потом уже сохранить в настройках пользователя.

Comment: Спасибо, значит буду переносить ее в NSData. А что значит (Я бы сохранял картинку в файл) через бинарный вид?

Comment: Да, в файл. Если картинка одна, можно хранить её всегда с одним именем. Если кучка однотипных, то можно в defaults хранить словарь с названиями файлов, или даже завести папку со всякими файлами программы — делайте выбор исходя из особенностей и перспектив роста Вашей программы.